# extending list of booleans by complements of another list of booleans

Tags: python, list, boolean

Given two lists `list1` and `list2` of booleans , I want to extend `list1` by the complements of the elements in `list2`. For example if

```
list1 = [True, True, False]
list2 = [False, False, True, False]
```

then after the operation

```
list1 = [True, True, False, True, True, False, True]
```

while `list2` shall remain unchanged.

What is the most pythonic way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```py
list1.extend(not value for value in list2)
```

If there is a risk that list2 is an alias to list1, you are better off with

```py
list1 += [not value for value in list2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_list = [not elem for elem in list2]
list1.extend(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generalize this to longer or more lists/arrays, you could have a look at numpy:

```
a1 = np.array([True, True, False])
a2 = np.array([False, False, True, False])
out = np.r_[a1, ~a2]
```

output: `array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True])`

Comment: no, I explicitly asked for lists.

Comment: @Walter that's why I specified the conditions to generalize, for simple cases as the one you showed, this is clearly overkill ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `not` keyword in the list comprehension, will just convert it to it's compliment.

```py
list1.extend([not value for value in list2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module provides the negation function, `__not__` or its alias `not_`

```
from operator import __not__

list1.extend(map(__not__, list2))
print(list1)
```